# $(document) vs. $("document")

Tags: javascript, jquery, document

Is there any difference between: `$(document)` and `$("document")`?

EDIT: also when into the `.ready()` e.g. `$("document").ready()`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`$(document)` uses jQuery to wrap the global `document` object.

`$("document")` attempts to look for a `<document>` element, which obviously makes no sense in HTML because there's no such element, only a root `document` object represented in the markup by the `<html>` element. It behaves that way because by passing the jQuery function a string, you're actually giving it a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors).

Re edit: as [patrick dw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785952/document-vs-document/4786022#4786022) says, in the context of `ready()` there's no difference, and in fact as of jQuery 3.0 using `$(document)` at all or explicitly calling `ready()` is deprecated. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready):

> jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> - `$( handler )`
> - `$( document ).ready( handler )`
> - `$( "document" ).ready( handler )`
> - `$( "img" ).ready( handler )`
> - `$().ready( handler )`
>
> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated. This is because the selection has no bearing on the behavior of the `.ready()` method, which is inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's behavior. For example, the third syntax works with `"document"` which selects nothing. The fourth syntax waits for the document to be ready but implies (incorrectly) that it waits for images to become ready.

Comment: So what's the difference between $("html") and $(document) then?

Comment: @Andrew: html is the document root element (document.documentElement), not the document object. If you want to modify the html element itself (e.g. by adding or removing class names), use $("html"), not $(document).

Comment: @BoltClock I want to add click handlers to the whole 'page', should I use $(document) or $("html") ?

Answer (score 8):

*If* you're talking about calling the `.ready()` function, it (currently) makes no difference.

In both cases the argument is ignored.

You could do this:

```
$( "cheese pizza" ).ready(function() {});
```

---

To be clear, it is best to use the officially supported calls to `.ready()`, which are:

```
$(document).ready(function(){/*...*/});
```

and:

```
$(function(){/*...*/});
```

When actually selecting the `document`, you should use `$(document)`.

Comment: Surely there actually is a difference. Are you saying that the `.ready()` call works on any jQuery object? If that's true, then why wouldn't you be able to use `$.ready(...)`?

Comment: @Greg,Bolt: I updated. I had imposed another thought into the question prematurely.

Comment: @Greg: Yes, you can do `$.fn.ready()`, though it isn't officially supported. http://jsfiddle.net/tmpTG/

Comment: well it's true in the case of `.ready()` - is it really the case that `$(document)` is functionally the same as an empty jQuery object? I've never really thought about it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery doesn't just walk away if you call `$()` alone with whatever argument. After all, `$()` is still a function on its own.

Comment: @Bolt: Again, I had imposed something into the question. My answer only applies to `.ready()`. Passing nothing to `$()` returns an empty jQuery object, so `.ready()` still works. http://jsfiddle.net/tmpTG/1/

Comment: @Bolt: That is a very gracious description of what was an embarrassing display of my wandering mind. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Your first example wil search for an variable or object called document within your JS. (be carefull, it is a predefined variable)

The second will search the page for a tag with the name "document".

```
var document = 'div#logo';
$(document); //will search for div#logo
$('document'); //will search for document
```

Answer (score 0):

`document` is a pre-made global variable that is the representation of the current HTML document, short for `window.document`.

`$("document")`, as @BoltClock pointed out, would be using that string as a selector for a `<document>` element.