# JQuery is not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using master page and content page. In content page I am using following jquery code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function() {
          var y = $("#<%hid.ClientID%>").val();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

```
<input type="hidden" id="hid" runat="server" />
```

When I run this code I am getting this error

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
```

```
Line 167:  @__w.Write("\").val();\r\n      });\r\n  </script>\r\n\r\n\r\n");
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right code is

```
var y = $('#<%=hid.ClientID%>').val();
```

`#` Tells jquery that find a control with given ID and `<%=hid.ClientID%>` gives the exact `ID`. Only `<%=hid.ClientID%>` this will not work. `'#<%=hid.ClientID%>'` is the right code.

Answer (score 3):

It is an ASP.NET compiler error message. You're missing an `=` from your output tag. It should be:

```
<%=hid.ClientID%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your problem, but document does not have to be in quotes

> $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: `document` is an object provided by any browser that has a [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), which means just about any browser released within the last 10 years.

Comment: @Damien Wilson, Jeff is saying something else.

Comment: But this usage won't cause a `Compiler Error Message`. I think it's the output from `<%hid.ClientID%>` which causes the error. On the other hand you are right with `$(document)`.

Comment: @Alex R: I'm aware, just thought it was pertinent information for anyone who wasn't familiar with the DOM or the javascript environment that runs within your run-of-the-mill browser.

Comment: @Alex R and @Damien Wilson what is the right syntax `<%hid.ClientID%>` or `<%=hid.ClientID%>`?

Comment: Ah, you guys are right, it was just an idea...  However I did find this interesting question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4785952/353278

Answer (score 1):

You could simply call

```
$(function() {
    var y = $("#hid").val();
});
```

if your input has a static `id`.

You should verify your resulting HTML / JavaScript code and see what `<%hid.ClientID%>` outputs.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be static. `runat=server` directive shows that ASP.net will generate some ugly client id for it instead of `hid`

Comment: @Snowbear JIM-compiler good point, missed that. So the last sentence may give him a direction to debug his error.

Comment: what is the right syntax `<%hid.ClientID%>` or `<%=hid.ClientID%>`?

Comment: to output the id `<%=hid.ClientID%>`

Answer (score 0):

This is an ASP.NET parsing error. The problem lies in the following line:

```
  $("#<%hid.ClientID%>").val();
```

You see, the <%= %>, not <% %>. So, it should look like this:

```
$("#<%= hid.ClientID %>").val();
```

Comment: But the, jQuery will never find the element, because `#` means: look for an element with the `ID`.