# Is one better? $(document) or $('document')

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty much what the title says. Is one of the two better? `$(document)` or `$('document')`.

It seems to me that if you use it quoteless it gets the dom object and with quotes it makes a new object, which makes it jQuery's responsibility. Right?

Comment: To create a new document fragment, you would have to use $('<document>').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your answer in Stackoverflow :) Check this out: [$(document) vs. $("document")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785952/document-vs-document)

But if you cant be bothered clicking the link:

$('document') will make jquery find the document element. But no such element exists - just the root DOCUMENT. jQuery will do more work to resolve this compared to the global document object.

Answer (score 4):

There is no better one - it's just whatever is correct.

$(document) is a jQuery object that represents the DOM.

$("document") is a jQuery object that represents DOM elements of type document, which there shouldn't be any as it's not a valid element.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use it without the quotes as it is the correct way to get the jQuery document object.

$(document).length returns 1.

The one with quotes actually try to get a html element called document, which does not exists in a usual HTML document.

$('document').length returns 0.