# Changing image src depending upon class

Tags: jquery, css

I have three images, of which only one can have selected status. Any one of them will get a class added dynamically. If that class is present I have to change the `src` of that image. Here is my code up to now, it has some problem with jQuery.

```
<div class="estart">            
    <div class="on-off-1">
        <img class="" src="img/on1.png" alt="">                        
    </div>

    <div class="on-off-2">
        <img class="dynamic-added-class" src="img/on2.png" alt="">                        
    </div>           

    <div class="on-off-3">
        <img class="" src="img/on3.png" alt="">                        
    </div>             
</div>
```

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".estart div img").ready(function() {
        if ($('.estart div img').hasClass('dynamic-added-class')){
          this.src = this.src.replace("on", "off"); 
        }
    });
});
```

off images are off1, off2...

Comment: Why not using the image as background image in CSS class and then toggle the class

Comment: Instead of `$("img").ready()` you may need to look at `.load()`. And even then, that might not work as expected. Take a look at the plugins such as [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).

Comment: you should try "img/on.png' and "img/off.png" , as src need full name of file also you have to verify the path of images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document.

So, do not use `$(".estart div img").ready(function() {`.

You may use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each) like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {//use document not 'document'
    $(".estart div img").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('is-selected')){
          this.src = this.src.replace("on", "off"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes. There's no element type of 'document', but we need to select document as the page.

Comment: But in the context of calling `ready()` it is not mandatory. Refer our SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785952/document-vs-document

Comment: Please read the answer carefully. `$(".estart div img").ready(function() {.` is wrong use.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use an image as a background rather than an image, you can then toggle just the class of the element which would then update your background. Giving the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var obj=$("img.dynamic-added-class");
     if(obj.length){ //check if there is any image with given class
        var src= obj.attr("src").replace("on", "off");
        obj.attr("src",src)
      }
});
```

**Demo:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y06d3ohj/)

why iterate and find the element when you can just check it directly